Getting an upper bound for the deviation of an estimate for the double derivative of an approximate polynomial
This is a kind of follow-up question to a previous question of mine. I now have more information on what can be done, and they are much less strict than I previously thought, and hence hopefully, a solution might just be possible. There was also an error in one of my estimates, so it's not so clear to me now as to how to proceed.
I will rehash the problem. I have a polynomial that looks like $$f(x)=n-\sum_{j=1}^nx^{d_j}$$ where $d_j\in\mathbb N$ (with $0\in\mathbb N$ and the convention that $0^0=1$). The only access I have to $f$ is blackbox access to the evaluations of $f$ in $[0,1]$, but the evaluations are imprecise, that is, on querying it the value of $f(x), x\in [0,1]$, it returns a value randomly from $\left((1-\epsilon)f(x),(1+\epsilon)f(x)\right)$ for some fixed $\epsilon>0$. The only gurantee we have is that the mean of the values at a specific $x$ is $f(x)$ (it can be assumed that the variance is $\eta$, but I would rather not use it unless really required). Oh and you have to fix the evaluation points before you start anything, that is, you can't look at the evaluation at one point and decide your next point!
I also now have the following piece of information given to me : $d_j\le t$ for all $j$. This is new, and I was avoiding it the last time.

The goal is to estimate $f''(1)$.

Obviously, the easiest thing to do is evaluate the polynomial at $t+1$ points, and get the unique interpolating polynomial $\hat f$. Differentiate it twice, apply it to 1 and we get $\widehat{f''(1)}$. I have done this using Newton polynomials with the evaluation points $\{j/t\}_{j=0}^t$ since it is easy to find the derivatives once we have the Newton coefficients.
What I want to understand now is how $$\mathbb P\left(|\widehat{f''(1)}-f''(1)|\ge \delta\right)$$ behaves, specifically an upper bound. More precisely, is the upper bound polynomial in $t$?
A little calculations show that $\mathbb E[\widehat{f''(1)}]=f''(1)$. This is simply because we can write (using lagrange interpolation) $$\hat f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^tD_{j/t}\ell_j(t)$$ where $D_{j/t}$ is a random variable taking values in $\left((1-\epsilon)f(j/t),(1+\epsilon)f(j/t)\right)$ with mean $f(j/t)$. Differentiating this twice and using linearity of expectation, the result follows.
So to get an estimate, one can use Chebyschev. But this is where I am stuck. Double derivative of the Lagrange basis polynomials is a nightmare (more so because $1$ is a point of evaluation). Using Bernstein polynomials, the derivatives are nice, but now the coefficients are (arbitrary) numbers, and it's not clear if they are uncorrelated (or even what their variances are) to break the variance of the sum as a sum of variances.
So my main questions are : Is there a way to get the variance of $\widehat{f''(1)}$? Or in some other way, bound $\mathbb P\left(|\widehat{f''(1)}-f''(1)|\ge \delta\right)$?
Or is my method doomed to fail? If so, what can be an alternate approach?
Any input is appreciated.

Lateral thought:  You don't say that $x$ is required to be a real variable.  Could you evaluate for $x \in \Bbb{C}$?  If so, you can evaluate on roots of unity for polynomial interpolation as in, for example [https://elec3004.uqcloud.net/ebooks/CLRS%20(2nd%20Ed)%20-%20Chapter%2030.FFT.pdf]

@EricTowers I did mention I need my $x$ to be in $[0,1]$!

Are you allowed to take multiple measurements of the same point? If so, taking large number of repeated measurements of the same point, the value you get should average out to the true value. You can do this until you have enough equations to solve the number of unknowns.

@Srini I can, but I would like to be efficient. So I can try it at every value maybe a constant number of time.
